# How can i get custom data attribute

Tags: javascript, custom-data-attribute

I can get the value of `id` but `data-id` shows this error,

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: id is not defined
```

My code,

```
<ul id="highscores"></ul>
<script>
var hst = document.getElementById("highscores");

var highScores = [
    { id: "1",name: "Maximillian", score: 1000 },
    { id: "2",name: "The second guy", score: 700 },
    { id: "3",name: "The newbie!", score: 50 }
];

function deleteById ( self ){
    console.log(self.id);
    console.log(self.data-id);
}
for (var i = 0; i < highScores.length; i++) {
        hst.innerHTML +=
        "<li >" +"<a data-id='test' id="+highScores[i].id + " href='#' onclick='deleteById(this)'>x</a>" +
        highScores[i].name +
        " -- " +
        highScores[i].score +
        "</li>";
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Hyphen is not a valid character in the property name when accessing a property with dot notation. When you do `console.log(self.data-id);`, the hyphen is evaluated as subtraction, and `id` is an undefined variable. Use `self.getAttribute('data-id')` instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Properties and attributes are two separate things. The `data-id` attribute you've defined does not automatically correlate to a property on that element. Similarly, e.g. an `<input type="text">` can have a `value` attribute, but the `value` property on it does not necessarily give you the value of that attribute, as the `value` property is pointing to what's currently in the input, whereas the `value` attribute is its initial value. Try to detach these two concepts.

To answer your question, though; there are two ways. One is to use `element.getAttribute('data-id')`. This works for any attribute. However, `data-*` attributes get their own fancy way to read and write their values; the `dataset` property. For example, to access the `data-id` property, you can use `element.dataset.id`. Similarly, to access the `data-foo-bar` attribute, you can use `element.dataset.fooBar`.

TLDR: Use `element.dataset.id` or `element.getAttribute('data-id')`